# Thumbnail of image appears but no image shows after taking screenshot of failed test case in extent reports

Tags: selenium-webdriver, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

**Code:**

```
public void tearDown(ITestResult result)

    if(result.getStatus()==ITestResult.FAILURE)    

    String screenshot_path= Utility.captureScreenshot(driver, result.getName());

    String image= logger.addScreenCapture(screenshot_path);
    logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Title verification", image);  

    report.endTest(logger);
    report.flush();
```

**Utility class function:**

```
public static String  captureScreenshot(WebDriver driver,String screenshotName)    

try 

TakesScreenshot ts=(TakesScreenshot)driver;

File source=ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File("./Screenshots/"+screenshotName+".png"));

System.out.println("Screenshot taken");

catch (Exception e)    

System.out.println("Exception while taking screenshot "+e.getMessage());

return screenshotName;
```

Thumbnail of image appears but no image shows after taking screenshot of failed test case in extent reports

Comment: I’ve just [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) improving [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
logger.fail("Title verification",MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath("Your image path").build());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot is failing because your captureScreenShot method returns the EXACT passed value of result.getname() instead of the desired "./Screenshots/"+screenshotName+".png"

If you print out the returned value, I think you'll find that's what's happening.

Alter your code as below:

```
String screenShotPath = "./Screenshots/"+screenshotName+".png";
FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File(screenShotPath));

...

return screenShotPath;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check before on Chrome/Firefox, I had something similar and you need to save the screenshot in the same folder with the report.